# How do I add custom UL LI format using foreach loop in magento

Tags: magento, loops, foreach, magento-1.7

```
I want to add my ul & li loop.. Example

Let's say I have infinite posts and I want the result should be like this

<ul>
 <li>Title 1 - content 1</li>
 <li>Title 2 - content 2</li>
 <li>Title 3 - content 2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Title 3 - content 3</li>
 <li>Title 4 - content 4</li>
</ul>

 <ul>
 <li>Title 1 - content 1</li>
 <li>Title 2 - content 2</li>
 <li>Title 3 - content 2</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

```
<ul>

    <?php $i=1; foreach ($posts as $post): ?>

    <li> <?php echo $i; ?>
    <div class="postWrapper">
        <div class="post_details">
            <?php if($post->getFeaturedImage()): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).$post->getFeaturedImage(); ?>" width="245" height="417">
            <?php endif; ?>

                <h2><a href="<?php echo $post->getAddress(); ?>" ><?php echo $post->getTitle(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php if($post->getSubTitle()):
                        echo '<p class="sub_title">'.$post->getSubTitle().'</p>'; 
                    endif;  
                ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>
<?php  $i++; endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="blog-grid3">
            <?php
                $k  =   3;
                $j  =   0;
                $i  =   1;
                foreach ($posts as $post):
            ?>
                   <li>
                        <div class="postWrapper">
                            <div class="post_details">
                                <?php if($post->getFeaturedImage()): ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).$post->getFeaturedImage(); ?>" width="245" height="417">
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $post->getAddress(); ?>" ><?php echo $post->getTitle(); ?></a></h2>
                                    <?php if($post->getSubTitle()):
                                            echo '<p class="sub_title">'.$post->getSubTitle().'</p>'; 
                                        endif;  
                                    ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li> 
            <?php        
                $j++;
                if($k==$j){
                    if($k==3){
                        $k  =   2;
                    }else{
                        $k  =   3;
                    }
                    $j  =   0;
                }
                if($j == 0 and $i!=count($posts)){ 

            ?>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="blog-grid<?php echo $k;?>">

                        <?php
        }
         $i++;  
        endforeach;
    ?>
</ul>
```

[image]